# Mongoose / MongoDB: count elements in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of a string in an array in my collection using Mongoose.  My "schema" looks like this:

```
var ThingSchema = new Schema({
  tokens: [ String ]
});
```

My objective is to get the top 10 "tokens" in the "Thing" collection, which can contain multiple values per document.  For example:

```
var documentOne = {
    _id: ObjectId('50ff1299a6177ef9160007fa')
  , tokens: [ 'foo' ]
}

var documentTwo = {
    _id: ObjectId('50ff1299a6177ef9160007fb')
  , tokens: [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
}

var documentThree = {
    _id: ObjectId('50ff1299a6177ef9160007fc')
  , tokens: [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ]
}

var documentFour = {
    _id: ObjectId('50ff1299a6177ef9160007fd')
  , tokens: [ 'foo', 'baz' ]
}
```

...would give me data result:

```
[ foo: 4, bar: 2 baz: 2 ]
```

I'm considering using MapReduce and Aggregate for this tool, but I'm not certain what is the best option.

Comment: Use `aggregate` unless you want the results persisted in their own collection.  You'll want to look at the [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/) operator for this.

Comment: So far, Mongoose's `mapReduce` class has added the temporary operator to the query, allowing the resultset to be returned rather than persisted.  Is there a reason beyond that that I'd want to use `aggregate` instead?

Comment: `aggregate` is often dramatically faster.

Comment: The aggregation framework was written precisely for handling queries like this (over map-reduce).  How much more performant it is I couldn't say, but higher performance and lower complexity for aggregation queries was the point.  Aggregation uses C++, while map-reduce uses (less performant) JavaScript [See the slideshow](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2011/mongodbs-new-aggregation-framework)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Aha, I've found the solution.  MongoDB's `aggregate` framework allows us to execute a series of tasks on a collection.  Of particular note is `$unwind`, which breaks an array in a document into *unique documents*, so they can be groups / counted *en masse*.

[MongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/) exposes this very accessibly on a model.  Using the example above, this looks as follows:

```
Thing.aggregate([
    { $match: { /* Query can go here, if you want to filter results. */ } } 
  , { $project: { tokens: 1 } } /* select the tokens field as something we want to "send" to the next command in the chain */
  , { $unwind: '$tokens' } /* this converts arrays into unique documents for counting */
  , { $group: { /* execute 'grouping' */
          _id: { token: '$tokens' } /* using the 'token' value as the _id */
        , count: { $sum: 1 } /* create a sum value */
      }
    }
], function(err, topTopics) {
  console.log(topTopics);
  // [ foo: 4, bar: 2 baz: 2 ]
});
```

It is noticeably faster than MapReduce in preliminary tests across ~200,000 records, and thus likely scales better, but this is only after a cursory glance.  YMMV.