# Mongoid Tags - Gather unique array items from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm build a Rails application with Mongoid and I need tags in one of my models.

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :options
  belongs_to :user

  field :title, type: String
  field :options_count, type: Fixnum, default: 0
  field :tags, type: Array
end
```

It works well and I can get all Question's tags using any_in

```
Question.any_in(tags:'foo')
```

But how can I get all tags from all documents in *Question*?

I'm trying to use map/reduce but it looks like I'm just sweeping all documents and treating the arrays in Ruby and it just doesn't feel right.

```
map = %Q{
  function() {
    emit(this.title, {tags: this.tags});
  }
}

reduce = %Q{
  function(key, values) {
    var result = [];
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      result.push(value.tags);
    });
    return result.toString();
  }
}

map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true).each do |doc|
  p doc['value']
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`db.collection.distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#distinct-method-array) for this. In your case, using Mongoid:

```
Question.distinct(:tags)
```

This will return an array of all tags in all documents with no repeated values.

Comment: How can I count the occurrence of all tags?

Comment: For that you will need to use the aggregation framework, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617379/mongoose-mongodb-count-elements-in-array