# How to count number of false values in an array mongo db query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
_id:5e4d18bd10e5482eb623c6e4
notification_obj:
 0  notification_text:"Welcome to the app and your account is created hello."
    open:false
    type:"just_click"

 1  notification_text:"Sebal started following you."
    open:true
    type:"open_profile"

 2  notification_text:"Hella started following you."
    open:false
    type:"open_profile"
```

So here I have an array 'notification_obj' array in a document of mongo database, I want to search the record with _id and in that record I want to count 'How many 'open:false' values are there. I want to count in this array that open:false how many times. Please help with a "query" in mongo db.

Comment: do a find query on the collection and then get the document/record and then do Array.filter and find the length of filtered array

Comment: How about some help with Aggregation function. I don't want to get the complete array from database. I want a query for mongo db.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose / MongoDB: count elements in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617379/mongoose-mongodb-count-elements-in-array)

Comment: @technophyle no this one is different. First I want to search the collection with _id and in that record I want to count number of true values in an array.

Comment: I know, but you can investigate the aggregate query in that answer and I believe you can achieve what you want with a small change. Hint: `unwind`.

Comment: @technophyle Ok I will try and tell you afterwards;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this code help you.

```
db.getCollection('your_collection').aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: ObjectId("5a544.............") }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$notification_obj'
  },
  {
    $match: { 'notification_obj.open': false }
  },
  {
    $count: 'total'
  }
]);
```

Output:

```
{
    "total" : 1
}
```

Comment: Had to change some things but this is the answer I was looking for thanks mayur.